# css not applying in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

So, I have this page, please view my `codepen` https://codepen.io/gianlucaps/pen/GRvVjmZ

so when I run this code on my live site, it looks perfect on safari, but when I run it on chrome, or Firefox, it looks absolutely terrible. the css is all over the place, certain things dont even fit on the page, I have no idea why. what am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine to me on Firefox other than the watch image getting squished on the mobile view

Comment: @abney317 when I run it in codepen, it looks fine, but when I run the code in an `index.html` file for example locally and then try It in browser, it doesn't work. did you try that way?

Comment: Probably has to do with the format of your html being messed up. Style should be inside the head tag. You're also missing a body tag and an html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work for you.

You need to remove height from here

```
.wrap { /*height: 100%;*/ display: flex;}
```

**NOTE: please set your code according to HTML format.**